# Подключение boost в netbeans Linux

Tags: netbeans, c++, linux

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как поключить библиотеку boost в netbeans (ОС Ubuntu 10.10). Из репозиториев скачал libboost1.42-dev, libboost1.42-all-dev, удовлетворил кучу зависимостей. В самом netbeans указал путь к библиотке. Но при компиляции выдает ошибку

```
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function 'main':  
/home/egor/NetBeansProjects/boost/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to 
'boost::thread::join()'
```

и т.д. по каждому методу.

Comment: Какая строка компиляции получается?

Comment: g++-4.5     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/boost build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o  
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `main':
/home/egor/NetBeansProjects/boost/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join()'
/home/egor/NetBeansProjects/boost/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `boost::thread::~thread()' и т.д.

Comment: Похоже, что неправильно настроили что-то. Я в netbeans не работал никогда, поэтому не знаю как это делается, но у компилятора должна появится опция -lboost-thread. Может быть можно ее прямо в опции компилятора добавить.

Comment: возможно дело в библиотеке из репозитория: там два варианта libboost1.42-dbg и 40. Установил 42.

Comment: В любом случае есть libboost_thread.so в dev-пакете.
Я перепутал надо добавить -lboost_thread

Comment: Спасибо, откомпилировал вручную g++ -lboost_thread -o test main.cpp, все прошло без ошибок. Теперь осталось понять почему netbeans не хочет компилировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойства проекта, linker, libraries (там кнопочка с ... нажимаем) в появившемся окне:
Add library (справа кнопка) и добавляем .a или .so библиотеку, обычно в /usr/lib/

Comment: саму библиотеку я уже давно добавил

Comment: ну а инклуд: <boost/thread/thread.hpp> есть ?

Comment: есть

Answer (score 1):

Не надо никакой путь указывать. Просто добавить -lboost_thread в опции линкера
[image]